# Plot K-Means in Matplotlib: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)

Tags: python, matplotlib, k-means

Please help me, thanks

I would like to perform a K means clustering on an image and plot it in matplotib, however it keep show this error:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)

Anyone know how to solve this?
My code is as shown below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\KaChun\Desktop\rotapple.jpg")
reshaped = image.reshape(image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], image.shape[2])

wcss = []
for i in range(1,11): 
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init ='k-means++', max_iter=300,  n_init=10,random_state=0 )
    kmeans.fit(reshaped)
wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plt.plot(range(1,11),wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method Graph')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you mean to put `wcss.append` inside the for loop?

Comment: Oops that's a careless mistake by me...

Comment: Yeah it worked fine by putting {wcss.append} inside the for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Error: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,)
and (1,)
Anyone know how to solve this? My code is as shown below:

```
import numpy as np    
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans    
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
            
            
# generating own data make_blobs
  X,y = make_blobs(n_samples=300, centers=4, cluster_std=0.60, random_state=0)
                plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1])
                
                
#elbow method
wcss=[]
for i in range(1,11):
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=i,init="k-means++",max_iter=300,n_init=10,random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(X)
wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1,11), wcss)
plot.title('elbow method')
plot.xlabel("number of clusters")
plot.ylabel('wcss')
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "f"have 
shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
if x.ndim  2 or y.ndim  2:
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) 
and (1,)**
```